# Unexpected return type from indexing object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to index a nested object. I expect the function to return a string type.

However, when i try to assign the return variable to a string it errors.

```js
const colors = {
  sea: {
    aqua: "#fff",
    blue: "#fff",
  },
  fruits: {
    red: "#fff",
    yellow: "#fff",
  },
};

type ColorsCategory = keyof typeof colors;

const myFunction = <T extends ColorsCategory>(
  category: T,
  color: keyof (typeof colors)[T],
): string => {
  const chosenColor = colors[category][color];
  return chosenColor;
  // ^? Type '{ sea: { aqua: string; blue: string; }; fruits: { red: string; yellow: string; }; }[T][string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
};
```

Comment: Does [this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2IBOEYF4YG8BQMYQFMBDALi1zxiIEcBXUmAIgGIAzdxgGgrwCN5aBMi3asuFAL7c8rJLQCWUCGRyUYSAgBNhbDtMoBPAvEQB3HaPF4p2CVVShIUANzZsUAwAcCMAMIhEFF8iKAIAc2QDdBgAawIDEFYYD29EuADkCFdsR2gYAFsDADFaMGAoeXBogB4AFRgCAA9QsE1Uf0CIYNCIpANOPwbmglbUOISkgAoUgjSETIBKAG1agF0APkmKYBDwyLJa-XmkMl9uBbJpr1mk44hltaXfVfR18jxc2GAACxBCMA6yGidyWOx6kVWoIySFWrjwGigtCQYDgv3+gKQrgk2U+MEa0UKJTKFXAkwA5IQiGSBmSaPQyQs4UA) work for you? If not, what am I missing? (I used `as const` assertion to improve the type of your function.)

Comment: Thank you @Lesiak . This is a good solution. Would be better if I didn't need to set explicit return type, but It works for me.

Comment: You mean the explicit return type of `myFunction`? I tried the code in playground, and it seems to work fine if you omit it (and get it inferred by TS)